# Modelstate is returning Isvalid = false on a valid object

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am using asp core 3.1  razor pages. On one of my page am posting JSON to razor pages post action. The model binding works perfectly. My issue is when I call ModelState.IsValid always getting false even if the JSON is valid.

Model class

```
 public class GLCode
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Description")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }


    }
```

Razor page Post action

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] GLCode GLCode)
        {
           // GLCode dd = new GLCode();
         // var result = await TryUpdateModelAsync(GLCode);



           // TryValidateModel(GLCode);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             //  return BadRequest(this.ModelState.GetModelStateErrors());
            }
            string desc = "";
            foreach (var modelState in this.ModelState.Values)
            {

                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error.ErrorMessage))
                        desc = desc + " " + error.ErrorMessage.ToString();

                    if (error.Exception != null)
                    {
                        desc = desc + " Exception: " + error.Exception.ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
}
```

When I Post Json request to the function, I am getting all values in the GLCode object .But when trying to validate the model always getting false.

Json request is {
  "Id":1,
  "Name": "tt",
  "Description": "hhhh"}

and getting this
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code instead of images

Comment: Does it also happen when you make the property non-nullable?

Comment: Yes .always getting false in model state @Tseng

Comment: Well I've seen similar happen, when the LangVersion is set to latest (means C# 8.0). If its blocking for you, try set back to C# 7.2 and recompile and/or use it conditionally

Comment: try use [Bind] instead of [FromBody]

Comment: I tested your code on a new razor pages 3.1 project , but ModelState.IsValid works well . [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/Eb_SfhymlIlPjSx0MU1FgvgBkSS7hvebTbeJ4YLgyGudwQ?e=EQrf0x) is my demo , you could refer to . If you need the community review and debug the code , could you share the detailed steps or a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Now I test my code another system . Now it is working. But could'nt figure out the issue. Vs studio versions are the same in both systems  @Xueli Chen

Comment: @gadasadox checked no result